# How do I make this app factor a polynomial with quadratic formula or some other trick?

Tags: polynomials, algebra, crystal-lang, quadratic-curve

How do I make this app factor a polynomial with quadratic formula or some other trick?.

The polynomial **3x^2 +10x -8** can be factored to **(x +4)(3x -2)** with the use of
[grouping](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/x2f8bb11595b61c86:quadratics-multiplying-factoring/x2f8bb11595b61c86:factor-quadratics-grouping/a/factoring-by-grouping) or [the X trick](https://youtu.be/YtN9_tCaRQc?list=PLj7OMLgK1gJcKBylwnesgZI9kLFfsRk_m&t=303). I would like my code to do this
but I have no clue how to accomplish it. My code factors the polynomial to **(x -0.6666666666666666)(x +4.0)**
which is not what I want from it.
This code snippet

```
require "option_parser"


puts "Please enter your variable values assuming the form ax**2 + bx + c ."

puts "a: "
a = gets
exit if a.nil? 
a = a.to_i 

puts "b: "
b = gets
exit if b.nil? 
b = b.to_i

puts "c: "
c = gets
exit if c.nil? 
c = c.to_i

the_gcd = a.gcd(b).gcd(a.gcd(c))

if the_gcd != 1

  x1 = (-1*b + (b**2 - 4*a*c) ** 0.5)/(2 * a)
  x2 = (-1*b - (b**2 - 4*a*c) ** 0.5)/(2 * a)

  if x1.to_i - x1 != 0 || x2.to_i - x2 != 0
    puts "The root is not a whole number. Consider grouping for factoring the polynomial."
    if x1 < 0 && x2 < 0
      puts "#{the_gcd}(x +#{-x1})(x +#{-x2})"
    elsif x1 < 0 && x2 > 0
      puts "#{the_gcd}(x +#{-x1})(x #{-x2})"
    elsif x1 > 0 && x2 < 0
      puts "#{the_gcd}(x #{-x1})(x +#{-x2})"
    elsif x1 > 0 && x2 > 0
      puts "#{the_gcd}(x #{-x1})(x #{-x2})"
    end    
    exit
  
  else
    if x1 < 0 && x2 < 0
      puts "#{the_gcd}(x +#{-x1.to_i})(x +#{-x2.to_i})"
      exit
    elsif x1 < 0 && x2 > 0
      puts "#{the_gcd}(x +#{-x1.to_i})(x #{-x2.to_i})"
      exit
    elsif x1 > 0 && x2 < 0
      puts "#{the_gcd}(x #{-x1.to_i})(x +#{-x2.to_i})"
      exit
    elsif x1 > 0 && x2 > 0
      puts "#{the_gcd}(x #{-x1.to_i})(x #{-x2.to_i})"
      exit
    end    
  end
   
  
  
  if (b**2 - 4*a*c) < 0
    puts "No real solution. Imaginary numbers involved in the solution."
    exit
  end

end

#The part below does not utilize GCD

x1 = (-1*b + (b**2 - 4*a*c) ** 0.5)/(2 * a)
x2 = (-1*b - (b**2 - 4*a*c) ** 0.5)/(2 * a)

if x1.to_i - x1 != 0 || x2.to_i - x2 != 0
  puts "The root is not a whole number. Consider grouping for factoring the polynomial."
  if x1 < 0 && x2 < 0
    puts "(x +#{-x1})(x +#{-x2})"
  elsif x1 < 0 && x2 > 0
    puts "(x +#{-x1})(x #{-x2})"
  elsif x1 > 0 && x2 < 0
    puts "(x #{-x1})(x +#{-x2})"
  elsif x1 > 0 && x2 > 0
    puts "(x #{-x1})(x #{-x2})"
  end    
  exit

else
  if x1 < 0 && x2 < 0
    puts "(x +#{-x1.to_i})(x +#{-x2.to_i})"
  elsif x1 < 0 && x2 > 0
    puts "(x +#{-x1.to_i})(x #{-x2.to_i})"
  elsif x1 > 0 && x2 < 0
    puts "(x #{-x1.to_i})(x +#{-x2.to_i})"
  elsif x1 > 0 && x2 > 0
    puts "(x #{-x1.to_i})(x #{-x2.to_i})"
  end    
end
   
if (b**2 - 4*a*c) < 0
    puts "No real solution. Imaginary numbers involved in the solution."
    exit
  end
```

is part [of a larger app](https://github.com/jerzybrzoska/algebra_with_crystal/tree/main/factor_quadratics) that deals with [other methods of factoring](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/x2f8bb11595b61c86:quadratics-multiplying-factoring/x2f8bb11595b61c86:factor-quadratics-strategy/a/factoring-quadratics-in-any-form) [quadratic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_function) as well.
Let these other methods of factoring, such as factoring perfect square trinomials or difference of perfect squares, be
outside of the scope of this question.
I came across a similar problem [in this Python code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36689/factoring-quadratic-equation), that apparently was solved with the use of fractions.
Might one utilize fractions in Crystal in order to solve my problem?

Comment: You could always try and port the python code to crystal...

Comment: You could use [BigRational](https://crystal-lang.org/api/1.2.0/BigRational.html).